# Highlight whole line in IRSSI when nick is mentioned

Tags: irssi

I can't seem to figure out how to visually highlight a line when my nick is mentioned... How can I do that in IRSSI?

I know that it lets you bold text, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do something more visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the default.theme or something close to it, just find the lines beginning with `pubmsgmenick` and `menick` and change them to be something like:

```
pubmsgmenick = "{msgnick $0 $1-}%R";
menick = "%R$*%n";
```

Where you can replace %R (dark red) with any color formats you want from https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/master/docs/formats.txt, including bold, underline and highlighting. Just make sure to have as many %n's at the end of `menick` as color formats at the beginning so that it doesn't bleed over into the closing angle bracket of the nickname formatting.